# how do i convert the value from str to int in my dict

Tags: python, python-3.x

`a: {'A': '120', 'B': '100', 'C': '100', 'D': '100'}`

how do I make it become this:

`b: {'A': 120, 'B': 100, 'C': 100, 'D': 100}`

Comment: Check https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0274/#id7. It's even simpler than the 1st example.

Comment: @Lulu use ```int(a['A'])```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
a = {'A': '120', 'B': '100', 'C': '100', 'D': '100'}

for x in a.keys():
  a[x] = int(a[x])
```

or this

```
a = {'A': '120', 'B': '100', 'C': '100', 'D': '100'}
a = {k : int(v) for k, v in a.items()}
```

Comment: ahh this is what i need, i checked the one they recommended but it's inside a nest and i am not really sure how to do it. thanks alot!

Comment: @Lulu You're welcome! Can you mark my answer as correct? I'd appreciate it a lot